# Rails on Dreamhost dedicated alongside existing PHP apps

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby, dreamhost

I'm a developer, and don't have much administration experience. The client wants to host a Rails 3.2 app on his Dreamhost dedicated server (running Debian) which already hosts a bunch of other sites (all have the same IP). I'm fine to go with Passenger/Apache setup, but I need ruby 1.9.3 on the server. Besides, Dreamhost have some custom Apache setup, and I'm not sure if manually editing httpd.conf will persist if the owner later adds a new virtual host through Dreamhost panel.

So, the essence of the question is: What's the best way to install Passenger/ruby 1.9.3 stack on Dreamhost dedicated without messing up the existing servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, why don't I read documentation until the end. Dreamhost wiki has [a guide for setting up RVM](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RVM). The last part tells about setting up a reverse proxy, which solves my problem.